# How resolve the right type in GraphQL when using interface and inline fragments

Tags: graphql

I'm facing a problem where I need to reference a resolved field on the parent from inside the __resolveType. Unfortunately the field I need to reference did not come as part of the original api response for the parent, but from another field resolver, which I would not have though mattered, but indeed it does, so it is undefined.

But I need these fields (in this example the; `obj.barCount` and `obj.bazCount`) to be able to make the following query, so I've hit a dead end. I need them to be available in the resolveType function so that I can use them to determine what type to resolve in case this field is defined.

Here's an example:

The graphql query I wish to be able to make:

```
{
  somethings { 
    hello
    ... on HasBarCount {
      barCount
    }
    ... on HasBazCount {
      bazCount
    }
  }
}
```

Schema:

```
type ExampleWithBarCount implements Something & HasBarCount & Node {
  hello: String!
  barCount: Int
}

type ExampleWithBazCount implements Something & HasBazCount & Node {
  hello: String!
  bazCount: Int
}

interface Something {
  hello: String!
}

interface HasBarCount {
  barCount: Int
}

interface HasBazCount {
  bazCount: Int
}
```

Resolvers:

```
ExampleWithBarCount: {
  barCount: (obj) => {
    return myApi.getBars(obj.id).length || 0
  }
}

ExampleWithBazCount {
  bazCount: (obj) => {
    return myApi.getBazs(obj.id).length || 0
  }
}
```

Problem:

```
Something: {
  __resolveType(obj) {
    console.log(obj.barCount) // Problem: this is always undefined
    console.log(obj.bazCount) // Problem: this is always undefined

    if (obj.barCount) {
      return 'ExampleWithBarCount';
    }

    if (obj.bazCount) {
      return 'ExampleWithBazCount';
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Any ideas of alternative solutions or what am I missing?

**Here's a little more about the use case.**

In the database we have a table "entity". This table is very simple and only really important columns are id, parent_id, name. type, and then you can of course attach some additional metadata to it.

Like with "entity", types are created dynamically from within the backend management system, and aftewards you can assign a type to your concrete entity.

The primary purpose of "entity" is to establish a hierarchy / tree of nested entities by parent_id and with different "types" (in the type column of entity). There will be some different meta data, but let's not focus on that.

Note: entity can be named anything, and the type can be anything.

In the API we then have an endpoint where we can get all entities with a specific type (sidenote: and in addition to the single type on an entitiy we also have an endpoint to get all entities by their taxonomy/term).

In the first implementation I modeled the schema by adding all the "known" types I had in my specification from the UX'er during development. The tree of entities could be like eg.

- Company (or Organization, ..., Corporation... etc)

  - Branch (or Region, ..., etc)
  - Factory (or Building, facility, ..., etc)

    - Zone (or Room, ..., etc)

But this hierarchy is just one way it could be done. The naming of each might be totally different, and you might move some of them a level up or down or not have them at all, depending on the use case.

Only thing that is set in stone is that they share the same database table, will have the type column/field defined and they may or may not have children. The bottom layer in the hierarchy will not have children, but machines instead. The rest of just diffent metadata, which I think we should ignore for to not complicate this further.

As you can see the hierarchy needs to be very flexible and dynamic, so I realized it wasn't a great solution I had begun on.

At the lowest level "Zone" in this case, there will need to be a "machines" field, which should return a list of machines (they are in a "machines" table in the db, and not part of the hierarchy, but simply related with an "entity_id" on the "machines" table.

I had schema types and resolvers for all in the above hierarchy: Organization, Branch, Factory, Zone etc, but I was for the most part just repeating myself, so I thought I could turn to interfaces to try to generalize this more.

So instead of doing

```
{
  companies{
    name
    branchCount
    buildingCount
    zoneCount
    branches {
      name
      buildingCount
      zoneCount
      buildings {
        name
        zoneCount
        zones {
          name
          machines {
            name
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And having to add schema/resolvers for all the different namings of the entities, I thought this would work:

```
{
  entities(type: "companies") { 
    name
    ... on HasEntityCount {
      branchCount: entityCount(type: "branch")
      buildingCount: entityCount(type: "building")
      zoneCount: entityCount(type: "zone")
    }
    ... on HasSubEntities {
      entities(type: "branch") {
        name
        ... on HasEntityCount {
          buildingCount: entityCount(type: "building")
          zoneCount: entityCount(type: "zone")
        }
        ... on HasMachineCount {
          machineCount
        }
        ... on HasSubEntities {
          entities(type: "building") {
            name
            ... on HasEntityCount {
              zoneCount: entityCount(type: "zone")
            }
            ... on HasMachineCount {
              machineCount
            }
            ... on HasSubEntities {
              entities(type: "zone") {
                name
                ... on HasMachines {
                  machines
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the interfaces being:

```
interface HasMachineCount {
  machineCount: Int
}

interface HasEntityCount  {
  entitiyCount(type: String): Int
}

interface HasSubEntities {
  entities(
    type: String
  ): [Entity!]
}

interface HasMachines {
  machines: [Machine!]
}

interface Entity {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  type: String!
}
```

The below works, but I really want to avoid a single type with lots of optional / null fields:

```
type Entity {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  type: String!
  # Below is what I want to avoid, by using interfaces
  # Imagine how this would grow
  entityCount
  machineCount
  entities
  machines
}
```

In my own logic I don't care what the entities are called, only what fields expected. I'd like to avoid a single Entity type with alot of nullable fields on it, so I thought interfaces or unions would be helpful for keeping things separated so I ended up with HasSubEntities, HasEntityCount, HasMachineCount and HasMachines since the bottom entity will not have entities below, and only the bottom entity will have machines. But in the real code there would be much more than the 2, and it could end up with a lot of optional fields, if not utilizing interfaces or unions in some way I think.

Comment: Have you tried storing a `__typename` field on each entity type? If an entity has a `__typename` field on it & implements an interface Graphql can infer what type to return. This would mean you would have to couple your Graphql logic with data access. Although you can use something like 'Virtuals'... you won't be able to get out of specifying what type each entity is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two separate problems here.

One, GraphQL resolves fields in a top down fashion. Parent fields are always resolved before any children fields. So it's never possible to access the value that a field resolved to from the parent field's resolver (or a "sibling" field's resolver). In the case of fields with an abstract type, this applies to *type* resolvers as well. A field type will be resolved before any children resolvers are called. The *only* way to get around this issue is to move the relevant logic from the child resolver to inside the parent resolver.

Two, assuming the `somethings` field has the type `Something` (or `[Something]`, etc.), the query you're trying to run will never work because `HasBarCount` and `HasBazCount` are not subtypes of `Something`. When you tell GraphQL that a field has an abstract type (an interface or a union), you're saying that what's returned by the field could be one of several object types that will be narrowed down to exactly one object type at runtime. The possible types are either the types that make up the union, or types that implement the interface.

A union may only be made up of object types, not interfaces or other unions. Similarly, only an object type may implement an interface -- other interfaces or unions may not implement interfaces. Therefore, when using inline fragments with a field that returns an abstract type, the `on` condition for those inline fragments will always be an object type and must be one of the possible types for the abstract type in question.

Because this is pseudocode, it's not really clear what business rules or use case you're trying to model with this sort of schema. But I can say that there's generally no need to create an interface and have a type implement it *unless* you're planning on adding a field in your schema that will have that interface as its type.

Edit: At a high level, it sounds like you probably just want to do something like this:

```
type Query {
  entities(type: String!): [Entity!]!
}

interface Entity {
  type: String!
  # other shared entity fields
}

type EntityWithChildren implements Entity {
  type: String!
  children: [Entity!]!
}

type EntityWithModels implements Entity {
  type: String!
  models: [Model!]!
}
```

The type resolver needs to check for whether we have models, so you'll want to make sure you fetch the related models when you fetch the entity (as opposed to fetching them inside the `models` resolver). Alternatively, you may be able to add some kind of column to your db that identifies an entity as the "lowest" in the hierarchy, in which case you can just use this property instead.

```
function resolveType (obj) {
  return obj.models ? 'EntityWithModels' : 'EntityWithChildren'
}
```

Now your query looks like this:

```
entities {
  type
  ... on EntityWithModels {
    models { ... }
  }
  ... on EntityWithChildren {
    children {
      ... on EntityWithModels {
        models { ... }
      }
      ... on EntityWithChildren {
        # etc.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The counts are a bit trickier because of the variability in the entity names and the variability in the depth of the hierarchy. I would suggest just letting the client figure out the counts once it gets the whole graph from the server. If you really want to add count fields, you'd have to have fields like `childrenCount`, `grandchildrenCount`, etc. Then the only way to populate those fields correctly would be to fetch the whole graph at the root.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've added some additional details to try and make the business rules and use case more clear. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a pretty complex case. If this is for an actual product, you might consider hiring a consultant to take a deeper dive into your schema with you. That said, it sounds like we're wrestling with three separate issues with the design: 1) Having dynamically named entities and not wanting to create a new type each time a new kind of entity is added; 2) Being able to type the hierarchy so that you don't end up with a bunch of extraneous null fields; and 3) being able to accurately capture the counts for.. child entities? Child entities and grand-child entities? Does that sound right?

Comment: 1) It is a requirement that this hierarchy is very flexible since some clients use different terms for closely related things eg. building, facility, factory, plant etc. Different levels of nesting is required. Eg. some would put machines directly under factory, and not have the "zone" level. and some would not have branches but plants directly under organization. I suspect grouping all possible levels into "kinds" of types and making an "alias" + "slug" fields so they can call it whatever might be a possibility. But doing this is much more redundant than using interfaces and inline fragments.

Comment: 2) Yes, after struggling with the above interface + inline fragment solution, I tried to make a single type Entity. The query will work just like the one in the question above, but with lots of null fields. It's nice how you can avoid all those duplicate field resolvers, but with all those null fields, it feels very wrong.
3) While we do use the counts, it's not really that important, but more an example for the use of interfaces. It could be a lot of things.

Comment: I feel it might be a mistake to transfer the concept of "entity" into the graphql schema, From a purely frontend perspective, it is not "entities", right? But a domain model consisting of those concrete types. Then I just need to figure out a good way or supporting aliases to the "kinds" of "types" can be aliased and custom slugs into whatever makes sense for the end customer. Do you have an idea whether that makes sense? type Entity with null fields is a no go, and if you cannot solve it with many smaller interfaces and composing your query with inline fragments, I cannot see any other way.

Comment: @Dac0d3r take a look at my edit. I don't think it's necessarily a mistake. Multi-tenant systems like these are hard to design well. I think keeping the abstraction at the API level is the right call given the constraints of GraphQL's type system.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but this looks a lot like the solution I tried initially. I just couldn't get the resolveType funtion to work, since I did not want to "fetch the related models/children when you fetch the entity" but wanted to "fetch them inside the models/children resolver" when you request it. Fetching all child entities when you fetch the parent entity would probably not impact performance much, but it still feels like a workaround and something I would run into everywhere where we currently fetch inside the resolvers. Given these limitations this it seems like an anti-pattern.

Comment: I think to me it would make more sense try and find common names for the different kinds of types in the hierarchy, add an alias+slug field and group them. Then make a type for each of them and then they all will have to implement the gql interface Entity. More  redundancy since it will add 10 new types to the schema, many of which will have largely the same fields and resolvers, but at least if I add the type field to the entity interface, and have all types as they own graphql schema type, I can use that field to resolve the right type in the Section interface's resolveType function.

Comment: But thanks. Now at least I know the limitations of the GraphQL type system.

Comment: So basically I'm back to making a type for each "kind" of type there is, but this time only for the "kinds" of types. Then the end customers can change the "display name" so a type of Organization might appear as Company, Corporation etc and also change the slug accordingly. But the underlying set of core types will have to be defined in GraphQL types that implements interface Entity that has the type field which is used in __resolveType.